# Sha 256 function from hashlib returns NoneType

Tags: python, hashlib

I have a variable c that contains a string gained from tkinters Entry object.
I want to apply a hash function to this string and than transmith it to some other computer.

I've already tried encoding my string with bytes function.

`bytes(c)`

or `encode` function

Else i tried using "cryptography" library and got the same error.

## I used hashlib library and created a variable  "digest"  that contains #hashlib.sha256() .

```
digest = hashlib.sha256()
```

## Than i applied an update function as it was said in documentation.

```
c = digest.update(c)                      

c = c.digest()
```

## And i've got an Error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HTTPS\Desktop\registration_form.py", line 79, in register
    c = c.digest()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'digest'
```

Comment: `digest.update(c)` doesn't return anything; it's called for its side effects, not its return value. Returning `None` is how it signals this.

Comment: i've called a "digest" function after.

Comment: Yes, but because you ran `c = digest.update(c)` and `digest.update()` returns None, you're subsequently calling the digest() function **on the `None` object**. That's why the error message tells you that `NoneType` objects don't have a `digest` -- you no longer have a `hashlib.sha256` object, you have a `None` object instead because you overwrote your sha256 object with the `None` object that the `update()` call returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = digest.update(c)
```

...should just be:

```
digest.update(c)
```

Operations which are called for their side effects in Python return None, to make it clear to callers that they're mutating the object on which they're called rather than returning a new value.